# Working with a button in a custom tableview Cell

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uibutton

I have a facebook like button in a custom tableview cell. In the class of my tableview I have the following function.

```
- (IBAction)sendLike:(id)sender
          WithString: (NSString *)shareString
              andUrl:(NSURL *)shareUrl{

          //Do all kinds of things


        [fbController setInitialText:shareString];
        [fbController addURL:shareUrl];
        [fbController setCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
        [self presentViewController:fbController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

In my cellForRowAtIndexpath I am trying to call this method in the following way.

```
 NSString *shareString = video.name;
        NSURL *shareUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:video.url];
        [cell.facebook addTarget:self action:@selector(sendLike: WithString:shareString andUrl:shareUrl)
                 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

But it is complaining that I should put ':' in my @selector. Can anybody help ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this

```
cell.facebook.tag = indexPath.row.
    [cell.facebook addTarget:self action:@selector(sendLike:)
                     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

in sendLike event

```
- (IBAction)sendLike:(id)sender
  {


        //if you want to fetch data from any list then try
        //UIButton *selectedButton = (UIButton*)sender;
        //data = [dataList objectAtIndex:selectedButton.tag];
        NSString *shareString = video.name;
        NSURL *shareUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:video.url];

        [fbController setInitialText:shareString];
        [fbController addURL:shareUrl];
        [fbController setCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
        [self presentViewController:fbController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
```

Comment: is it possible that you have a typo in the first piece of code ? cell.facebook.tag = ...

Comment: I think it should be cell.facebook.tag = indexPath.row;

Comment: yes Andy you are right...usually i handle situation like this way :)

Answer (score 0):

As its in the apple documentation, the only available specifications for an `@selector` in an action are the following methods:

```
- (void)action;

- (void)action:(id)sender;

- (void)action:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
```

As you can see, your selector doesn't match this, because you have multiple arguments, but only the sender `id` is allowed.

As a solution, you can probably set a `tag` for your button and then handle it in your selector.

Answer (score 0):

In your `cellForRow`:
//wiring a custom string to a button

```
objc_setAssociatedObject(yourButton, "theKey", strText, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
```

In your button handler:

```
NSString *str = objc_getAssociatedObject(sender, "theKey");
```

p.s don't forget to import runtime library:
`#import <objc/runtime.h>`

Answer (score 0):

I think you invoked the selector in wrong way. You actually should write,

```
[cell.facebook addTarget:self action:@selector(sendLike: WithString: andUrl:)  
                                     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

But this doesn't pass arguments for you. If you want to pass arguments, you should call ***performSelector*** like

```
[self performSelector:@selector(sendLike: WithString: andUrl:) 
                                withObject: cell.facebook
                                withObject: shareString
                                withObject: shareUrl];
```

Hope it will help solving your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the number and kind of arguments are incorrect in your selector. You can only use targets with the following scheme:

```
 - (void)action;
 - (void)action:(id)sender;
 - (void)action:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
```

You will have to include your information in the sender (the `UITableViewCell` class instance) object. You can do that as described in the other answer by Stas, but I would recommend you to create a custom table view cell subclass which adds a property for `shareString` and `shareURL`. This approach will require more code, but make it much easier to *read, maintain and prevents this ugly Obj-C and C mix up.*